# Internet Explorer cannot display page

Tags: internet-explorer

I have checked the hosts files and they seem ok.

I have check to see if there was a proxy active which there wasn't.

I am unsure of what else to check. I am currently doing a virus and malware scan. The internet works in Firefox, Safari and Chrome but not Internet Explorer. I am using Internet Explorer 7 on Windows Vista Home.

Comment: Is this one page/site or any?

Comment: sorry it was on any site

Comment: I'd suggest checking your DNS resolution but that should have affected all browsers.

Comment: i can ping google.com

Comment: is there anything else you suggest?

Comment: No - sorry, out of ideas at the moment.

Comment: Set internet security in IE to defaults, clear cookies and temp IE files. Try to login as different user. Also install and try with some other browser - FF, Chrome, Opera, Safary etc.

Comment: Why do you use IE 7? Why don't you use IE 8?

Comment: have you done as @jet suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to exclude temporary internet files and others?

Tools > Internet options > General > Browser history > Delete... > choose all > Try to navigate

Or have you tried to disable add-ons?

Tools > Internet options > Programs > Manage extensions > Click on each add-on and choose "disable" > Try to navigate

(well, I use the SO in Portuguese, so I would miss some translations)

Comment: i have started internet explorer with out addons but still no joy